# How to add user input to an array and show it the end

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

my code is a math game with random number this is a small part of the code that shows the question and asks for the user answer how do I store every question and user answer in an array

```
  sss = Convert.ToString(answer);
                question = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", num01, op, num02);
               
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                 Console.WriteLine("What is = " + question+ " Or type QUIT to ignore ");
                useranswer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: There are lots of possible answers to this question, but you should first make yourself familiar with using arrays in general. An array of numbers is declared as `int[] numbers = new int[<size>];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two dimensional array, but you must know how many questions/answers you will store in advance:

```
string[,] array = new string[10, 2]; // 10 is how many columns (questions) you want to store, 2 defines that you want to store 2 values (question and answer) in each column
// this is how you add items to your array
array[0, 0] = question; // the first zero defines that you are adding the first item, the second one that it is question
array[0, 1] = answer; //the second one defines that you add answers
```

You can access your questions and answers the same way that you save them: `array[0, 1]` will return the first answer.

If you don't know how many questions you will save in advance, you should use List or Dictionary instead of array.